# How to properly create a child theme structure

Tags: themes, directory-structure, wordpress

I've read some articles and I've understood that there are Child theme files, that could totally override the Main theme files but others not (like `function.php` for example). At this point, will be good to know which files could be included in the Child theme and how (regarding the folder structure).

Most of my modifications are made in `custom css` Main theme special field, but also I've modified directly `app.css`, `app.min.js`​, `header.php`, `script-calls.php` (registering additional `js` files and applying some tweaks)​.

I have to mention that in my case, stylesheets are enqueued using `inc/script-calls.php` not `function.php` file.

All the files (no matter what extension) could be treated in the same way, Is that ok if I simply copy these files into the Child theme folder or should I create an exact directory structure, like we have in the [Main theme](http://goo.gl/9Xz6GM) please?

Thank you,

LE: I am struggling to make it work but without result. I recreate the same folder structure trying to use these files in the child: `app.css`, `app.min.js`​, `header.php`, `script-calls.php` and the only file that is working it's `header.php`. Any thoughts?

​

Answer (score 1):

You have to follow the directory structure of the Parent theme in the child theme folder.

If your Parent theme structure is:

```
/parent-theme/templates/single.php
```

To replace the single.php in the child theme folder you must create:

```
/child-theme/templates/single.php
```

Any file can be included in your child theme. you can also include additional files that are not loaded in the parent theme.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

Comment: Thank you for your feed-back Claudiu, your answer reffer to pages/templates but we are talking about setting files. Are you 100% the same rule could be applied in Child theme structure? :) to be honest I went here because codex it's pretty confusing taking in consideration my theme structure described above (stylesheets are enqueued using `inc/script-calls.php` not `function.php file`)